# Duplicate row changing certain columns?

Tags: mysql

I want to copy row with ID = 1 to a new row in the same table. But two columns (UID and Date) must not be the same as the original row.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `Posts` (`A`,`B`,`UID`,`Date`) VALUES
```

How do I get all values from row with ID = 1 but change UID to 2 and Date to NOW()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `Posts` (`A`,`B`,`UID`,`Date`) 

SELECT col1, col2, `your definedvalue1`,`your defined date `,
 FROM this_table
WHERE 1>0(your condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `Posts` (`A`,`B`,`UID`,`Date`) 
select a, b, 2, now() from `Posts` where UID = 2;
```

See **[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f60d6/1)**

Comment: i think it is give an error  you can not you `Values` in this statement

Comment: I think he means you must use VALUES() in the statement. Anyhow I'm not being able to make it work.

Comment: @Liso22 I added a fiddler example

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
INSERT INTO Posts (`A`,`B`,`UID`,`Date`) 
SELECT `A`,`B`,`UID`,`Date` FROM Post
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UID =2 DATE =NOW()
```

**Note:** make index on UID and Date column

Comment: I cannot make index of either columns.